# Blob custom metadata gives null on search

Tags: metadata, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to use blob custom metadata in my azure search. I have tried loads of multiple ways but my result keeps giving me null.

After many tried, at this moment I have configured the following (which isnt working!):
Blob storage with custom metadata:
pageurl =

In the index I have configured the following:

```
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_pageurl",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
```

In the indexer:

```
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default"
    }

    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_pageurl",
      "targetFieldName": "pageurl",
      "mappingFunction": null
    }
```

In the skillset:

```
          {
            "name": "metadata_storage_pageurl",
            "source": "/metadata_storage_pageurl",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
```

What would I need to do to ensure that a search actually provides the blob custom metadata?

What I have tried is to mix between:

- metadata_storage_pageurl or just pageurl
- Using /document/ infront of it.
- Many other things.

Comment: Can you verify that the indexer is configured to pull metadata from the blob storage. To do this, you need to add the "dataToExtract" property with the value "allMetadata" in your indexer configuration. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#configure-and-run-the-blob-indexer) for details.

Comment: Hello, I am using the Content and Metadata option for this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Did you try "/document/metadata_pageurl" in your skillset index projections definition? So with the "/document" but without "storage". That should be what works.</s>

My bad, you don't need "metadata_". The `source` in your index projections definition should just be "/document/pageurl".

You need to ensure that the `name` in the index projections matches the `name` of the field in the index. So if you update one you have to update the other. I would then remove the `fieldMappings` in the indexer definition (that is for the "parent" index, which if you are using index projections I'm guessing isn't your primary index) as having it might cause some other weird mappings and renames to happen, since `fieldMappings` are applied before skillset execution.

Comment: I did try to change it to /document/metadata_pageurl, but nothing. How should i then have the index and indexers configured?

Comment: Did you try this in a debug session? It's usually the fastest way to figure out what happens in a skillset.

Comment: Apologizes, I had a misunderstanding. Updated my answer to be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carey. That was the solution!
To summarize:
Add the exact name of the metadata from the storage blob as field in the index:

```
{
  "name": "pageurl",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": true,
  "filterable": true,
  "retrievable": true,
  "sortable": true,
  "facetable": false,
  "key": false,
  "indexAnalyzer": null,
  "searchAnalyzer": null,
  "analyzer": null,
  "normalizer": null,
  "dimensions": null,
  "vectorSearchProfile": null,
  "synonymMaps": []
}
```

Then head to the skillset and add the following there:

```
{
  "name": "pageurl",
  "source": "/document/pageurl",
  "sourceContext": null,
  "inputs": []
}
```